# C++ ansi Escape Code Doesn't Color The Text

Tags: c++, g++, ansi-escape

I'm trying to use ANSI escape codes to color a text, my code looks like this:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {

    std::cout << "\033[31m" << "\n";
    std::cout << "\033[1;31m" << "\n";
    std::cout << "\\033[31m" << "\n";
    std::cout << "\\033[1;31m" << "\n";
    
    return 0;
}
```

which is fairly simple, but the output I get is equal to this:

```
C:\Users\User\Desktop>a.exe
←[31m
←[1;31m
\033[31m
\033[1;31m
```

I use g++, and I didn't add any other options other than the cpp file itself

Comment: Well, that depends on the terminal you use? What's your operating system?

Comment: It works on my side. Double backslash is not correct though, you either have to add another one or remove one. The compiler doesn't matter, just the Console or the OS if you are using the default Console.

Comment: I made a function to color the terminal text to some RGB value in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77083302/20785822) based on the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-virtual-terminal-sequences). This (and your first two prints) should work with the Windows terminal.

Comment: @yonutix Yes I know That double Backslash didn't work but It were worth a shot, Im using default windows 10 Command Prompt

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Windows 10, Command Prompt

Comment: Do you have ANSI escape codes enabled in your Windows 10 Command Prompt?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755142/how-to-make-win32-console-recognize-ansi-vt100-escape-sequences-in-c (read all the answers)